# Getting an Imageview all screen wide and not distorted

Tags: android, android-glide

I am working on an Android app. There I have a recyclerview which is populated from a remote server JSON file.
On the recyclerview  there is as Imageview.

The image that is shown at the Imageview may have different orientations. It can be portrait, landscape or square.

I could use the scaletype attribute to get the image output as desired, but my client wants to show the image always at full screen width.

And on the other hand, I need to put a reasonable limit for the height attribute.

That means, I need an Imageview with a specific height range (150dp-250dp for example) and then I need the Imageview attribute to full screen width.

I am using Glide to download the images from a remote URL.

What should I do first to get an image not distorted in any of the three cases, portrait, landscape, square?

Comment: What happens the full-width image's height exceeds your max allocated value?

Comment: What you want is impossible.  If you stretch an image and don't maintain aspect ratio, you will see distortion and/or image loss on the sides.  Especially if you want landscape and portrait on the same image.  You cna pick some images that will still do that and look ok, but they need to be specific image types (no important data at the sides as they may be chopped off, preferably vector images, not photos.  Simple color/gemoetric patterns work best.